# xcode7 'UIViewController' has no member 'viewDidLoad'

Tags: xcode, member, viewdidload

I have links to images which I turned to comments underneath the last }. Using Xcode7, ALL my code is:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
  }
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidload()
  }
}
```

> Error: Value of type
>   `UIViewController` has no member `viewDidload`

I've searched for a solution with no result, Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The error message is correct:

```
super.viewDidload()
```

is a non-existent function, however, changing it to:

```
super.viewDidLoad()
```

Should then be recognized; the upper/lowercase of each word in the function **is important**.